# Find the volume of the body bounded by $z = x^2 + y^2, z= 1-x^2-y^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Again, I am new to volume of bodies and I am struggling with it.

> Find the volume of the body bounded by $z = x^2 + y^2, z= 1-x^2-y^2$.

Now from a previous question, I know that I can do it by $\iint_{D} {z_2(x,y) - z_1(x,y)dxdy}$.

In this case, here's what I did:

$V = \iint_{D} {[2x^2 + 2y^2 -1] dxdy}$. But I struggled with what $D$ is in this case. Is it two circles centered at $(0,0)$ with radiuses $\sqrt{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ or am I missing something here?! These questions are driving me crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Cylindrical Coordinates for it again. Note that having $x^2+y^2$, usually, sign us to use this coordinate rather than Cartesian ones. First of all find the area in which the whole volume is established on. What is that? For doing this and for this question, intersect two functions. $$x^2+y^2=z=1-x^2-y^2\longrightarrow x^2+y^2=1/2$$ This means that that desire area is a circle on $xy$ plane as $x^2+y^2=1/2$. 
[image]

Now, lets do some polar conversations. $$x^2+y^2=1/2\longrightarrow r^2=1/2,~~ \theta\in[0,2\pi]$$ or $$r\in [0..\sqrt{2}/2],~~\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$ So we have: $$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{2}/2}\int_{z_1}^{z_2}r dr d\theta$$ Now make a guess what may that $z_1$ and $z_2$ be. If you don't know the triple integrals, we can do $V$ as follows instead:
$$V=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{2}/2}(z_2-z_1)~r dr d\theta$$

[image]

Comment: Is the last one a three variable integral? If so, we haven't learned it and I should do it in two.

Comment: @TheNotMe: See above

Comment: I see! Well I am wondering about something. At times, we have two $z$ functions and then we intersect them to get our $D$, like here. At times, we got only one function of $z$ so we take the second as $z=0$ and take the other equation as our $D$. And at different times we do different things.
How can I ever make sure that what I am doing is legitimate?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Why $z=0$?? When you make them to be intersect each other, yes, we find just one rule for $z$ that is $x^2+y^2=1/2$ here. What you are saying about $z=0$ and taking another for $D$ doesn't seem right, at least here.

Comment: Yes, not here. Here we certainly can't take $z_2 = 0$. But in my previous question I think we can. Anyway I calculated my previous question, have a look at my answer and please tell me if you had the same answer.

Comment: @TheNotMe: Ok I 'll do

Comment: Very nice diagrams (where do you get them from, @BabakS.?!) and explanation. +1

Comment: @TheNotMe, with the notation Babak used: $$z_2=1-x^2-y^2=1-r^2\;,\;\;z_1=x^2+y^2=r^2\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: Dear Don, I made it by Maple 16. Thanks for your kind consideration.

Comment: $\quad \large +\to +\infty\quad$

Comment: @BabakS.: I love the beautiful illustrations and pictures are so helpful! +1